# Normative Fragen

Tags: discussion

Wie sollen wir mit normativen Fragen umgehen, d.h. mit Fragen, die nach der Richtigkeit oder Falschheit sprachlicher Ausdrücke fragen?

Comment: Gibt es vielleicht ein gutes Beispiel für so eine Frage auf German.SE? Mir fallen gerade nur solche ein, die als offtopic geschlossen wurden (wegen "proofreading" oder "dictionary")

Answer (score 5):

Ich denke, eine Antwort auf eine normative Frage sollte *deskriptiv* und *problembewusst* sein, sie sollte *sprachliche Varietäten* und auch den *Sprachwandel* berücksichtigen und auf den eigenen Horizont *reflektieren*:

## Deskriptiv

Es gibt keine autoritative Instanz, die über die Richtigkeit und Falschheit im Deutschen urteilen kann. Es gibt die amtliche Rechtschreibung, aber die ist nur für Staatsbedienstete in Ausübung ihres Dienstes verbindlich.

Da es keine verbindliche Autorität gibt, sollten wir uns eine solche auch gar nicht erst anmaßen. Wir sollten also keine normativen, sondern deskriptive Antworten geben. German.SE ist nicht dazu da, Fragen über die deutsche Sprache zu *entscheiden*, oder die deutsche Sprache zu verändern, sondern dazu da, Fragen über die bestehende deutsche Sprache zu *beantworten*.

Ein abstraktes Beispiel:

> 1) Diese und jene Formulierung ist falsch.
>
> 2) Diese und jene Formulierung wird von den meisten kompetenten Sprecher*innen des Deutschen als falsch angesehen.

1) ist eine normative Aussage, 2) eine deskriptive.

Nur deskriptive Antworten lassen sich herrschaftsfrei diskutieren, normative nicht.

Für die Benutzer der Seite ist es wichtig ist, die sozialen Gepflogenheiten zu kennen, die faktische Akzeptanz bestimmter Ausdrucksweisen. Daher ist es wichtig, die Akzeptanz der in Rede stehenden Ausdrucksweise in einer deskriptiven Antwort so gut wie möglich zu charakterisieren. Ein bloßer Verweis darauf, dass es keine Autoritäten gibt, ist damit eine schlechte Antwort, weil sie an dem in der Frage artikulierten Bedürfnis vorbeigeht.

## Problembewusst

Wir sollten bei jeder normativ gestellten Frage reflektierend auf die oben geschilderte Problematik normativer Fragen hinweisen.

Wenn ein Ausdruck für "falsch" gehalten wird, sollte man immer die Autorität nennen, die dieses Urteil fällt, weil jede Autorität nur begrenzte Gültigkeit hat, und die Angabe damit relativierend wirkt. Ein Beispiel:

> 1) Die Konjugation 1. Pers. Pl. Präs. Ind. Aktiv von *schreiben* als *mir schreibed* zu verwenden, ist falsch.

und

> 2) Die Konjugation 1. Pers. Pl. Präs. Ind. Akt. von *schreiben* als *mir schreibed* zu verwenden, weicht von der im Duden angegebene Konjugation ab.

sind verschiedene Aussagen, und 2) ist die bessere Antwort.

## Varietäten berücksichtigend

In der Antwort sind regionale und soziale Varietäten zu berücksichtigen und zu benennen. Die Frage sollte die verschiedenen Vorstellungen so gut wie möglich beschreiben, sich einer abschließenden Wertung selbst aber enthalten. Wenn also die Frage etwa lautet

> Ist der Satz
>
> *Der Mensch, wo Sokrates heißt.*
>
> richtig?

Dann sollte man darauf hinweisen, dass das maskuline Relativpronomen im Standarddeutschen *der* lauten müsste, dass im Schwäbischen jedoch *wo* als Relativpronomen für alle Genera verwendet wird, dass die Wahrnehmung dieses Satzes also vom Kontext abhängt, dass außerdem gegenüber Sprecher*innen von Dialekten diskriminierende Einstellungen verbreitet sind, und dass es daher für einen selbst hilfreich sein kann, *wo* als Relativpronomen zu vermeiden, wenn man sich außerhalb Schwabens befindet.

## Sprachwandel berücksichtigend

In der Antwort sollte man auch das Phänomen des Sprachwandels berücksichtigen. Meinem Eindruck nach, basieren viele Fragen nach Korrektheit auf Wandelungen der Sprache. Oft habe ich den Eindruck, dass die Fragestellenden zu wenig über das Phänomen des Sprachwandels reflektieren, und sich hier eine normative Bestätigung holen wollen.

So ist die Konjugation 2. Pers. Sgl. Präs. Ind. Akt. von *erhalten* als *du erhälst* noch vor einigen Jahren als falsch zu bewerten gewesen. Mittlerweile begegnet man dieser Form aber so häufig, dass man hier nicht mehr nur von einem individuellen Fehler sprechen kann. Eine Antwort sollte also darauf hinweisen, dass die Konjugation nicht im Duden steht, dass sie aber in letzter Zeit vermehrt auftritt, sodass es möglich ist, dass hier ein einsetzender Sprachwandel zu beobachten ist.

## Reflektierend

Regionale und soziale Varietäten und auch Phänomene des Sprachwandels sind praktisch niemandem vollständig bekannt. Sprachwandel ist auch nicht einmal immer aktuell wissenschaftlich erfassbar. Ein intuitiver Zugang (nach "Sprachgefühl" oder persönlicher Erfahrung) ist daher nicht hinreichend, um diese Fragen zu beantworten.

Hält man einen Satz für "falsch", sollte man also immer die Begrenztheit des eigenen sprachlichen Horizonts bedenken und diese ausweisen.

Grundsätzlich würde ich sagen, dass man die Formulierung *Das ist falsch.*, oder *Das ist schlicht falsch* mit großer Vorsicht verwenden sollte. Gerade die letzte Formulierung scheint mir (nicht nur hier auf german.se) ein Indiz für zu sein, dass man eigentlich einen normativen Kampf führen will, statt einer deskriptiven Aufklärung zu liefern.

Comment: Grundsätzlich unterstütze ich das Anliegen. Allerdings gibt es hier auch viele Sprachlerner, die sich im Anfangsstadium befinden. In diesem Fall erscheint mir die Verkürzung auf die Dichotomie richtig – falsch als angemessen und die Überwältigung des Fragestellers mit Fakten zu diatopischen, diachronen und Registervarianten als unangemessen. Und man muß zugeben, daß die präskriptive Perspektive oft vom Fragesteller eingefordert wird ("Wie muß es heißen?") und eine aufgeklärtere Sicht des Antwortenden somit ein Mißverhältnis der Perspektiven bedeutet.

Comment: @DavidVogt Ich stimme dir zu, dass man auch die didaktische Methode nicht vergessen sollte. Allerdings sind wir hier kein Forum, sondern eine Wissenssammlung. Die Antwort sollte also nicht nur den individuell Fragenden im Blick haben, sondern auch Leute, die später hier vorbeikommen und die Antwort sehen. Ideal wäre es, wenn die Antwort beides vereint: Eine didaktisch simplifizierte Version und danach eine ausführliche, reflektiertere Antwort.

Comment: Präskriptiv und Deskriptiv sind keine Gegensätze, insofern die Preskriptive weit genug verbreitet jst. Selbst Proskriptiv kann angebracht sein, insofern durch gute Argumente gestützt, etwa "Anglizismen, Lateinische Lehnworte, etc sind nicht allgemeinverständlich", zumal es unmöglich erscheint, es jedem Recht zu machen und jede Mindermeinung zu berücksichtigen. Gerade daher lebt dieses Forum von der Vielfältigkeit, so wie die Sprache selbst von Vielseitigkeit geprägt ist. Ansonsten wäre die Frage paradox.

Comment: @vectory In meinen Augen sind präskriptive und deskriptive Aussagen kategorial voneinander verschieden. Präskriptive Aussagen sagen: "Ich erwarte X von dir", deskriptive Aussagen machen sich diese Erwartung nicht zu eigen, sondern sagen: "Viele Menschen werden X von dir erwarten". Das ist ein ganz anderer Aussagegegenstand und auch eine andere Haltung.

Answer (score 1):

In [meiner ersten Antwort](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1490/15393) schrieb ich

> Es gibt keine autoritative Instanz, die über die Richtigkeit und Falschheit im Deutschen urteilen kann. Es gibt die amtliche Rechtschreibung, aber die ist nur für Staatsbedienstete in Ausübung ihres Dienstes verbindlich. Da es keine verbindliche Autorität gibt, sollten wir uns eine solche auch gar nicht erst anmaßen.

Das würde ich mittlerweile etwas genauer fassen:

In sprachlichen Fragen sind alle Autoritäten *relativ*. Damit meine ich: Autoritäten sind auf einen bestimmten Geltungsbereich beschränkt. Diese Beschränkung ändert nichts daran, dass Autoritäten innerhalb ihres Geltungsbereichs nichtsdestotrotz wirksam, d.h. verbindlich sind.

Eine Antwort bietet einen Mehrwert, wenn sie möglichst viele Geltungsbereiche abdeckt. Es ist für Sprachverwender:innen relevant ob eine sprachliche Regel A) im Duden steht, B) in der Schule gelehrt wird, C) in einem Gesetz oder einer Verodnung für den Behördengebrauch geregelt ist oder D) der privaten Auffassung von Richtigkeit eines einflussreichen Kolumnisten entspricht.

Eine Antwort ist besser, wenn sie:

- viele Geltungsbereiche abdeckt
- deutlich herausarbeitet, auf welche Autorität sich die Regel jeweils stützt

Das heißt also, Antworten auf normative Fragen sollten eine möglichst genaue Beschreibung der relevanten, d.h. wirkmächtigen normativen Positionen geben.

Comment: "In sprachlichen Fragen sind alle Autoritäten relativ" - Bin nicht überzeugt. Auch die Peer Pressure, die entsteht, wenn man Muttersprachler, die (anscheinend) nicht richtig sprechen, lesen, schreiben, können, belächelt, ist eine Art (allgegenwärtige) Autorität.

Answer (score 0):

Fast alle Fragen sind normativ, wenn auch oft nicht expressis verbis.

Die Antwort, dass es nur die amtliche Rechtschreibung gibt, die auch nur für Staatsdiener in Ausübung ihres Amtes verbindlich ist, geht am Problem vorbei.

Nicht nur gibt es Schüler und Deutschkursbesucher, die keinen geringen Teil unseres Publikums ausmachen. Außerdem ist jeder Bürger, der Verträge eingeht, auf die normative Beurteilung von Aussagen angewiesen, oder Werbetreibende.

Wir alle sind ständig darauf angewiesen uns richtig auszudrücken, wenn wir richtig verstanden werden wollen - nur ist es oft nicht juristisch einklagbar. Das bedeutet aber nicht, dass nur juristische Konsequenzen von Belang sind. Wenn der Freier seiner großen Liebe eröffnet, dass er sie mag, statt das richtige *liebt* zu verwenden, hat das zwar keine juristischen, wohl aber ernsthafte Konsequenzen, die zu berücksichtigen sind.

Dass wir kein Juristenforum sind sollte jedem klar sein. Wenn unklar ist, ob nicht doch eine juristische Frage gestellt wurde, muss man eben in den Kommentaren nachfragen.

Comment: Das ist aber keine Antwort auf die Frage, wie mir normativen Fragen umgehen sollten.

Comment: Doch, wir gehen mit ihnen wie mit allen Fragen um: Wenn sie in unser Profil passen versuchen wir sie zu beantworten, passen sie gut, sind ordentlich gestellt, ausreichend vorbereitet und keine Verdopplung bereits beantworteter Fragen werten wir sie auf. Sind sie unklar fragen wir nach.

Comment: Ich habe mich missverständlich ausgedrückt. Ich meinte nicht, ob wir sie upvoten oder downvoten sollen, sondern auf welche Art und Weise wir sie beantworten.

Comment: Ja, und die Antwort hängt davon ab, ob derjenige zu erkennen gibt, Angst vor rechtlichen Sanktionen zu haben, dann würde ich ihm schon mitteilen, dass Falschschreibung nicht verboten ist, aber das würde ich nicht in jeder Antwort schreiben.

Comment: Magst du das in Deiner Antwort noch mehr ausführen?

Comment: Es bringt aber auch nichts, sich darauf zu berufen, dass man laut Wörterbuch das Wort *Freier* richtig benutzt hat, wenn die meisten zuerst an eine andere als die gemeinte Bedeutung denken.

Comment: @CarstenS: Inwieweit ist es denn von Belang, ob die meisten zuerst an die gemeinte Bedeutung gedacht haben, wenn sie dann merken, dass die 2. Bedeutung gemeint sein muss?